# Bootstrap 3 Styling Container Class

Tags: css, customization, twitter-bootstrap-3

What I'm looking for might be very basic if someone is using bootstrap for a while.

I'm looking for a way to style the body background let say #ebebeb and the container background #fff with a padding of 10px, if you go search something on m.Google.com you will see exactly what I'm talking about.

Somehow I cannot figure out how to do it with Twitter Bootstrap 3.0.2
[image: see screenshot]

Comment: You can't just override the Bootstrap CSS with your own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please edit your question and provide your code? There could be more than one issue causing the problem, and it'll be easier to help you if I can see your code.

If I had to guess, I'd say the easiest way achieve what you want would be something like this:

```
body { 
  background: #ebebeb; 
} 
.container { 
  background: #fff; 
}
```

Make sure that you're including this CSS **after** you've included bootstrap.css, otherwise it won't override the default styles set by Bootstrap. Here's a the fiddle that shows this: http://jsfiddle.net/5KwP3/1/

One thing to be aware of however, is that anything that isn't in the `container` div won't have any padding by default.

Comment: as you can see in screenshot the white background of the container should not cover the width (right and left) of the screen. I just want similar effect with bootstrap.

Comment: @OmarAbdirahman. You ought to make a best effort. The body will have a padding too if you don't want the container to hit the edge. http://jsfiddle.net/5KwP3/2/

Comment: Ahaa, now it looks better. I didn't thought of the padding in body. Excellent Christina :)